# Зачем нужна конструкция "const {products} = ... " ? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, frontend

Не могу понять что куда записывается и как называется данная конструкция. Примера на 165 строке

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это Деструктуризация объекта https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment)

```
let options = {
  title: "Menu",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

let {title, width, height} = options;

alert(title);  // Menu
alert(width);  // 100
alert(height); // 200
```